# JS await execution and then placement

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following code,

```
    await getAuthFailedAttempts().then((attempt) => {
      errorMessage = VALIDATION_ERROR;

      if (!attempt.canRetry) {
        errorMessage = createFailedAttemptsError(attempt);
      } else {
        setAuthFailedAttempt();
      }

      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        passcode: "",
        validationError: errorMessage,
      });
```

So how to rewrite to use await properly,

```
    const attempt = await getAuthFailedAttempts();
```

and how to place the "then" for "attempt"?

thanks in advance

Comment: Dont use the then. Await the promise, with the result do what you need. It is all inside an async function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there-- once you have assigned the result of `getAuthFailedAttempts()` to `attempt` using `await` then what was the body of your `.then` simply comes behind it:

```js
const attempt = await getAuthFailedAttempts();
errorMessage = VALIDATION_ERROR;

if (!attempt.canRetry) {
  errorMessage = createFailedAttemptsError(attempt);
} else {
  setAuthFailedAttempt();
}

this.setState({
  loading: false,
  passcode: "",
  validationError: errorMessage,
});
```

Please note that to use `await` the containing `function` must be an `async function` declaration.